# Publishing app to the app store as application manager without developer account

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect, developer-program

[image: Check the image.]I am publishing an app to the app store for the first time. I have an apple id but do not have an developer account.

The admin added me to iTunes connect as an application manager.

Can I publish an app to the app store without developer account as an application manager? If so, then kindly let me know how do I do that.

Please explain the answer very clearly because I am new to iOS platform.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you an Agent, Admin or Member? There is no 'application manager' role for iTunesconnect.

Comment: I did editing and added a snapshot of what I am looking at.

Comment: This page might be helpful, wrt the abilities of each type of user. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/UsingiTunesConnect/UsingiTunesConnect.html

Answer (score 1):

You can only add apps if you are at least have an agent or admin user rol.

Steps to submit a new app:

1. Go to [iTunesconnect](http://itunesconnect.apple.com)
2. Click on 'My Apps'
3. Press the **+** in the top left corner
4. Fill in the details provided by your developer (Bundle ID etc)

Now you created a new app in iTunesConnect. To publish an app you need to fill in all details of the app and let the developer upload a *build* . In the app details you need to link the build to your version.

Comment: What is an agent user?

Comment: @codename_mak Since a developer needs to add you - why not have them ask Apple Support if needed - they are paying for support as part of their dev service.

Comment: An agent is the superadmin of the account. It can even change bank account settings and other usefull stuff.